# Location manager not monitoring Beacons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, geolocation, cllocationmanager, clbeacon

I am not getting region entry and exit events for beacon regions. This is how I add the beacon to the monitoredRegions:

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString: beacon.UUID];
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:      uuid major: (CLBeaconMajorValue) beacon.major  minor: (CLBeaconMajorValue) beacon.minor  identifier:  @"SOME IDENTIFIER"];

[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion: region];
```

and events:

```
- (void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *) manager didEnterRegion:   (CLRegion *) region
{
    NSLog(@"entered  beacon region");
}

- (void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *) manager didExitRegion: (CLRegion *) region
{
    NSLog(@"exited beacon region");
}
```

None of these delegate events are called for this beacon region.

I have tested this with geographical regions and it works but it just does not work for my beacon. Also I have tested the ranging on this same beacon which works.

Are there any known issues with beacon monitoring??

Many thanks

Comment: For the benefit of anyone having this issue, i have found that the plist file has to be updated with a few more attributes in iOS8.2 ( may have been earlier):  to the "Required background modes" property add 2 new items:
    "App shares data using CoreBluetooth"
    "App registers for location updates”    ( this is in addition to already needed properties: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and/or  NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Answer (score 1):

Hi @ldsarria Check my steps its working for me

**Step 1 :** Set delgate in .h file  CLLocationManagerDelegate

**Step 2:**

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
```

**Step 3:**

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"SOME IDENTIFIER"];
        CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] 
        initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.test.abc"];
                region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay =YES;
                [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

**Step 4:**
Set NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription = "This app needs your location to hunt some treasure."

Cheers!!!

Comment: Hi mshau, thank you very much, I had this but the actual problem was two attributes that weree needed in the plist for  "Required background modes" property :"App shares data using CoreBluetooth" and "App registers for location updates